# TypeScript::Nestgram + ConfigModule:: vanilla versions and error

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Pls help to solve this problem
I've got vanilla nestgram framework and now i'm trying to add support of ConfigModule, but see the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

the problem starts when I'm adding the line in *app.module.ts*
`imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()]`

The problem seems in nest-gram.js (*node_modules/nestgram/dist/nest-gram.js*)

```
static async getServices(Module) {
        const modules = Reflect.getMetadata('modules', Module) || [];
        const compiledModules = [];
        for (const module of modules) {
            let result;
            let err;
            try {
                result = await module();
            }
            catch (e) {
                // @ts-ignore
                result = module();
                err = e;
            }
            if (result) {
                try {
                    compiledModules.push(...result);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                }
            }
        }
        let services = Reflect.getMetadata('services', Module)

       * //=> MY FEAUTURE FOR DEBUGGING
    console.log(typeof(services))
        //MY FEAUTURE FOR DEBUGGING <=
*
    services = services.map((Service) => {
            return new Service(...compiledModules);
        });
        return services;
    }
```

my `console.log(typeof(services))` returns
*undefined
object
*
when I add `imports:[ ConfigModule.ForRoot()]`
and only *object* if not

help pls

==================================================================================

*main.ts*

```
import { NestGram } from 'nestgram';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  let KEY=process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY
  console.log(KEY)
  console.log(typeof(KEY))
  const bot = new NestGram(KEY, AppModule);
  await bot.start();
}

bootstrap();
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from 'nestgram';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';


@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  services: [AppService],
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*app.controller.ts*

```
import { OnCommand, Controller } from 'nestgram';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService?: AppService) {}

  @OnCommand('start')
  start(): string {
    return 'Hello, world!';
  }
}
```

*app.service.ts*

```
import { Service } from 'nestgram';


@Service()
export class AppService {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume it would have to do with this warning on the front page of their docs:

> Nestgram can't use Nest.js modules. But you can create own modules for Nestgram :)

Seems you won't be able to use `@nestjs/config` with this package.

From the looks of it, nestgram is **heavily** inspired by NestJS, and may even use Nest under the hood, but it is not interoperable with existing NestJS packages.

Comment: You're right. my fault
Thx a lot